# How to remove quotation marks in lists in Python (trinket)

Tags: python, list, quotation-marks

I'm trying to have trinket print out an entire list without printing the quotation marks surrounding each index. A plain print(list) isn't working, and neither are any of the more elaborate options such as print(*list, sep =', '). I'm relatively new to coding so apologies if this request is impossible/ridiculously easy.
What I'm trying to avoid: ['a','b','c','d']

Comment: Then don't print the *list* but only its items. Quoting text strings is one of the things Python does by default, when printing a list.

Comment: @Mark Meyer I guess he only wants to get rid of the quotations, not the brackets.

Comment: The apostrophes are there, because the are practically always useful. It may be important, whether you have the number *9* or a string containing the digit 9. If you are absolutely sure, that your list contains just strings, you should have stated so.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `str.join` to represent the list yourself. E.g.

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d']

print(f'[{", ".join(lst)}]')
```

Comment: [@guidot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435475/guidot): No, it doesn't. `repr` returns `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, and we replace the `'` with nothing so we get `[a, b, c, d]`.

Comment: Fixed wording. Second solution suffers from filtering the quotes also, if they were within a string. I can't imagine that as expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, that's true. If the elements contains any apostrophe then they will also be stripped. I agree, while this works for the provided example, this indeed cannot be expected behaviour. Removed that solution from the post, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "f" throws up a bad input in trinket - my main problem with any of the methods I've tried to find on the internet. If I remove it I do get a workable result though - so thank you!